# OS X: Unload process from launchctl

Tags: macos, launchctl

I need to stop collectd for a while.
I can see it's running:

```
ps axuw | grep collectd
user    73543   0.0  0.0  2540860   1900   ??  S     4:15PM   0:00.26 /usr/local/Cellar/collectd/5.4.0/sbin/collectd -f -C /usr/local/etc/collectd.conf
```

**kill [PID]** kills the process but it starts again.

I can see it in launchctl list:

```
launchctl list | grep collectd
73543   -   homebrew.mxcl.collectd
```

But I cannot find its plist:

```
mac:~ user$ ls /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep -i "collectd"
mac:~ user$
mac:~ user$ ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep -i "collectd"
mac:~ user$
```

So I have no idea how to unload it.
Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you use `launchctl stop` instead of kill?

Comment: @lzam:
 
    `mac:~ user$ launchctl stop 73543`

     `launchctl stop error: No such process`

Comment: I don't think you can call `launchctl stop` with a PID you need the label. you can try to find it with `launchctl list`. Note that you may need to use `sudo` for both commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the plist in

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
```